# How to write Java regular expression to tokenize strings?

Tags: java, regex, tokenize

I am able to tokenize part of a string, but not the entire string. I need assistance on writing a regular expression to tokenzie the entire string. The string I am trying to tokenzie is 123+56*num1.

The regular expressions below are the ones I have already tried. I can tokenize 123+56*, but not 123+56*num1. It would be great if the expression could match variable names as well.

```
String variableRegex = "[a-zA-Z_$0-9][a-zA-Z_$0-9]*"; //for variable names
String operatorRegex = "\\+|-|\\/|\\*|\\*|="; // for operators
String multiply = "\\*";
String numberRegex = "\\d*";
String definingVariables = String.format("(%s)(%s)(%s|%s)(%s)", variableRegex, operatorRegex, variableRegex, numberRegex, multiply);
String justVariable = String.format("%s", variableRegex);
String allRegex = String.format("%s|(%s)", definingVariables, justVariable);
```

The result should be:

123

+

56

*

num
1

The current result is:
123+56*num1

Comment: How come you can have `+` and `*` in your variable name regex? And if alphabets are appearing altogether with numbers like `num1`, then will that `num1` not be a variable name? What's your rationale to split `num1` into `num` and `1`? [This regex](https://regex101.com/r/wMwrMc/1) although splits your string the way you want but I am not sure about your other regexes defined in your post.

Comment: I took out + and * out of the variable name regex. I put those in there just to try it out. Thanks for pointing out num1. That is a validate variable name so it is okay. I went ahead and also changed that. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, see my answer below for getting your expected tokens, but I see one more issue in your variable regex. Writing `[a-zA-Z_$0-9][a-zA-Z_$0-9]*` and `[a-zA-Z_$0-9]+` is same, isn't it? Also for your `operatorRegex` you can easily write it in a character set where you don't need to worry for escaping them. Write them as `[-+/*=]`

Comment: Thank you. Those two regular expression are more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```java
"[0-9a-z]+|\+|\*"
```

See https://regex101.com/r/rzhoyx/1/.